# What does "Suite name" define in Publish options menu?

Tags: wpf, clickonce, publishing

When publishing several WPF apps, writing the same name on `'Suite name'` seems to override the previous app in the Start Menu folder. 
The `Publisher name` more or less defines the Start Menu subfolder name and `Product name` defines the application name. And if I just leave the `Suite name` blank all the apps are in the Start Menu subfolder together. From what I could find about it, it should define a group of things that will be used together.

So my question is: What does `Suite name` even define?